# Is there a way to simulate a null value so request is not sent to backend with Capybara/rspec?

Tags: rspec, capybara

I want to simulate in a dnd that a object was dropped with no position set,so request is not sent to backend. I'm using capybara with rspec. I haven't found something similar to this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by dropped with no position set?

Comment: Sometimes you dropped somewhere outside the list or the list itself but position couldn't be set. In those cases the API request should't be performed.

Comment: so just drag it to an element outside the list